# Is Kafka 0.7.2 compatible with Storm 0.9.3.1

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

I am thinking about upgrading from Storm 0.9.0.1 to Storm 0.9.3.1. I have a lot of legacy code that was written against Kafka 0.7.2 and would prefer to keep that as is and not upgrade to Kafka 0.8+. Will upgrading Storm affect any code that interacts with Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are running them independently I don't think there should be any issues.